# print UTF-8 character in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

Here is how I open, read and output. The file is an UTF-8 encoded file for unicode characters. I want to print the first 10 UTF-8 characters, but the output from below code snippet print 10 weird unrecognized characters. Wondering if anyone have any ideas how to print correctly? Thanks.

```
   with open(name, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
        for i in range(10):
            print content[i]
```

Each of the 10 weird character looks like this,

```
�
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: share the text file contents

Comment: Your console or tty must support the character as well - you might have to change your terminal settings.

Comment: @cdarke, thanks and vote up. My console could `print content` correctly, which should prove it supports UTF-8 characters. The issue only happens if I print `content[i]`. If you have any thoughts, it will be great.

Comment: @RahulKumar, thanks and vote up. Not sure how to post original raw file here, I tried and my console could `print content` correctly, which should prove it supports UTF-8 characters. The issue only happens if I print `content[i]`. If you have any thoughts, it will be great.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When Unicode codepoints (characters) are encoded as UTF-8 some codepoints are converted to a single byte, but many codepoints become more than one byte. Characters in the standard 7 bit ASCII range will be encoded as single bytes, but more exotic characters will generally require more bytes to encode.

So you are getting those weird characters because you are breaking up those multi-byte UTF-8 sequences into single bytes. Sometime those bytes will correspond to normal printable characters, but often they won't so you get � printed instead.

Here's a short demo using the ©, ®, and ™ characters, which are encoded as 2, 2, and 3 bytes respectively in UTF-8. My terminal is set to use UTF-8.

```
utfbytes = "\xc2\xa9 \xc2\xae \xe2\x84\xa2"
print utfbytes, len(utfbytes)
for b in utfbytes:
    print b, repr(b)

uni = utfbytes.decode('utf-8')
print uni, len(uni)
```

**output**

```
© ® ™ 9                                                                                                                                        
� '\xc2'                                                                                                                                       
� '\xa9'                                                                                                                                       
  ' '
� '\xc2'
� '\xae'
  ' '
� '\xe2'
� '\x84'
� '\xa2'
© ® ™ 5
```

Stack Overflow co-founder, Joel Spolsky, has written a good article on Unicode: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You should also take a look at the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) article in the Python docs, and Ned Batchelder's [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) article, aka "Unipain".

---

Here's a short example of extracting individual characters from a UTF-8 encoded byte string. As I mention in the comments, to do this correctly you need to know how many bytes each of the characters is encoded as.

```
utfbytes = "\xc2\xa9 \xc2\xae \xe2\x84\xa2"
widths = (2, 1, 2, 1, 3)
start = 0
for w in widths:
    print "%d %d [%s]" % (start, w, utfbytes[start:start+w])
    start += w
```

**output**

```
0 2 [©]
2 1 [ ]
3 2 [®]
5 1 [ ]
6 3 [™]
```

FWIW, here's a Python 3 version of that code:

```
utfbytes = b"\xc2\xa9 \xc2\xae \xe2\x84\xa2"
widths = (2, 1, 2, 1, 3)
start = 0
for w in widths:
    s = utfbytes[start:start+w]
    print("%d %d [%s]" % (start, w, s.decode()))
    start += w
```

If we don't know the byte widths of the characters in our UTF-8 string then we need to do a little more work. Each UTF-8 sequence encodes the width of the sequence in the first byte, as described in [the Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

The following Python 2 demo shows how you can extract that width information; it produces the same output as the two previous snippets.

```
# UTF-8 code widths
#width starting byte
#1 0xxxxxxx
#2 110xxxxx
#3 1110xxxx
#4 11110xxx
#C 10xxxxxx

def get_width(b):
    if b <= '\x7f':
        return 1
    elif '\x80' <= b <= '\xbf':
        #Continuation byte
        raise ValueError('Bad alignment: %r is a continuation byte' % b)
    elif '\xc0' <= b <= '\xdf':
        return 2
    elif '\xe0' <= b <= '\xef':
        return 3
    elif '\xf0' <= b <= '\xf7':
        return 4
    else:
        raise ValueError('%r is not a single byte' % b)


utfbytes = b"\xc2\xa9 \xc2\xae \xe2\x84\xa2"
start = 0
while start < len(utfbytes):
    b = utfbytes[start]
    w = get_width(b)
    s = utfbytes[start:start+w]
    print "%d %d [%s]" % (start, w, s)
    start += w
```

Generally, it should *not* be necessary to do this sort of thing: just use the provided decoding methods.

---

For the curious, here's a Python 3 version of `get_width`, and a function that decodes a UTF-8 bytestring manually.

```
def get_width(b):
    if b <= 0x7f:
        return 1
    elif 0x80 <= b <= 0xbf:
        #Continuation byte
        raise ValueError('Bad alignment: %r is a continuation byte' % b)
    elif 0xc0 <= b <= 0xdf:
        return 2
    elif 0xe0 <= b <= 0xef:
        return 3
    elif 0xf0 <= b <= 0xf7:
        return 4
    else:
        raise ValueError('%r is not a single byte' % b)

def decode_utf8(utfbytes):
    start = 0
    uni = []
    while start < len(utfbytes):
        b = utfbytes[start]
        w = get_width(b)
        if w == 1:
            n = b
        else:
            n = b & (0x7f >> w)
            for b in utfbytes[start+1:start+w]:
                if not 0x80 <= b <= 0xbf:
                    raise ValueError('Not a continuation byte: %r' % b)
                n <<= 6
                n |= b & 0x3f
        uni.append(chr(n))
        start += w
    return ''.join(uni)


utfbytes = b'\xc2\xa9 \xc2\xae \xe2\x84\xa2'
print(utfbytes.decode('utf8'))
print(decode_utf8(utfbytes))
```

**output**

© ® ™
© ® ™

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring, vote up for your reply. Tried your method works pretty good. Have a further question, if the original string has both Unicode character (e.g. Chinese/Japanese characters) and also have English characters in the same string with UTF-8 Encoded, suppose the first character is Chinese character, the 2nd character is a ASCII letter `a` (both are UTF-8 encoded). After I call `utfbytes.decode('utf-8')`, when I refer the 2nd character by `utfbytes[1]`, will it be able to recognize `a` correctly?

Comment: (cont'd) I have this confusion since you mentioned multi- and single- byte characters, and I am wondering how they would work if mixed in the original UTF-8 encoded string. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I tried when refer `utfbytes[1]`, `a` could be output correctly, just to confirm my understanding is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: I'm glad you figured it out; I didn't reply earlier because it was 3AM in my timezone when you posted your comments. It's tricky indexing into a string like `utfbytes` unless you know the byte sizes of the components. FWIW, Unicode handling in Python 3 is generally better (and  less confusing) than it is in Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

To output a Unicode string to a file or to the console you need to choose a text encoding. In Python the default text encoding is ASCII, but to support other  characters you need to use a different encoding, such as UTF-8:

```
s = unicode(your_object).encode('utf8')
print s
```

Comment: Thanks U.Swap, vote up. Shall I replace `your_object ` in your code by `content `?