# Transform ascii to unicode

Tags: python, utf-8

I am not able to convert

```
'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.encode("utf-8")
```

the following to unicode, but cannot, getting the error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

I would like to get

```
'Schutztüren'
```

as a result.

Comment: Oups, `''Schutzt\xc3\xbcren''` is not ASCII! ASCII codes must be in range 1-127. It is the utf-8 encoded byte string for `'Schutztüren'`. In the same idea, you encode a unicode string to a byte string with an encoding and decode a byte string to an unicode string.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I have tuples that contain these strings and these tuples are cells in a DataFrame that I save to disk with `.to_csv`. I get these ugly strings. How do I get them on disk in a nice format?

Comment: @Make42, switch to Python3, then add `encoding="utf8"` both to `df.to_csv()` and and when you read your file. Everything will Just Work.

Comment: @alexis: No can do. Company policy for now.

Comment: Saw your other message, I sympathize. See my reply there.

Comment: @alexis: But the `encoding="utf8"` works also in Python 2, as I just tried and found out.

Comment: hspander gave you the way for a single value. Try to implement it for your dataframe and feel free to ask a new question refering to this one is you can't.

Comment: @Make42, on `to_csv()` it does, yes. But not on (plain) `open()`. And the problems that `Python 3` solves are much broader. Editing my answer.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 5):

Your string is already in `utf-8`. You need to *decode* it to Unicode in order to use it inside Python:

```
print 'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")
```

But you have a bigger problem: You are clearly using Python 2. Switch to Python 3 immediately, there is no reason to drive yourself crazy trying to understand the Python 2 approach to handling character encodings. Switch to Python 3 and you will not have to bang your head against your desk several times a day. (Note that although you were calling the `encode()` method, you got a 
`UnicodeDecodeError`.

A simple explanation:

- In Python, `unicode` and `utf-8` are different things. A `str` in Python 2 might be in the `"utf-8"` encoding, `unicode` objects have no encoding.
- If you try to use a `str` for something that requires `unicode` (e.g., to `encode()` it), or vice versa, Python 2 will try to implicitly convert it first. Except it doesn't know the encoding of your strings, so it guesses (`ascii`, in your case). Oops.
- Python2 has a lot of implicit conversions.

But really the reason is simple: You are not using Python 3.

**Edit:** Since Python 3 is not an option, here is some practical advice:

1. [Unicode sandwich](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html): Convert all text to Unicode as soon as it's read in, work with `unicode` strings and encode back to a utf8 `str` only to write it out again.
2. Pandas should still support the `encoding` argument to `to_csv()`, even on Python 2. Use it to write your files in `utf8`.
3. For reading a file directly, use `codecs.open()` instead of plain `open()` to read files. It accepts the `encoding=` argument and will give you `unicode` strings.

Comment: Sure, I would love to, but... company policy for now.

Comment: Ouch... you're in for a world of hurt. If it's a new project, try the ["unicode sandwich"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html) approach (convert everything to unicode as soon as you read it, convert back to `str` only when writing to files).

Comment: I've been using Python2 since 1999, still using it daily, and I never feel the need to "bang my head against my back". Python2 "approach to handling character encodings" is nothing complicated, really - unless you don't have a clue about unicode, byte strings and encodings of course but then Python3 won't help.

Comment: @bruno, that's because you have been using it since 1999! :-) Of course it works pretty well if you already know it. But wrapping one's head around this now, when Python 3 is available, is useless pain. And Python 3 will help *a lot* if you don't have a clue. I teach this stuff so I say so from experience. The Python 2 version isn't worth the trouble to teach to beginners-- and by extension to anyone, unless they have no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `decode` utf-8 encoded string to unicode instead.

```
'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: It worked. Can you explain how you came to this solution?

Comment: `'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")` results in `u'Schutzt\xfcren'` - so not working for me.

Comment: To explain in bit more detail, utf-8 is an encoding to store unicode characters. Normally a unicode character is formed of 2 bytes i.e. 16 bits. Conventionally ascii characters used to be stored and represented by single byte. So utf-8 is an encoding that allows unicode characters to be stored separately in two separate bytes, and then combine them for rendering them as unicode characters.

Comment: @Make42: it works. `'\xfc'` is the unicode code for `'ü'`, or in unicode notation U+00FC. `print 'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")` should give correct output (if your terminal is correctly configured).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you please let me know too about how to configure the terminal for the issue. I also have been facing this issue for quite a while.

Comment: @hspander It is a different question, and really depend on Python version (assuming Python 2 here) and the OS. First search SO for [python] unicode console for Windows, or terminal for Linux-Unix

Comment: [UTF-8 is a variable length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). You may find my code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38653062/4014959) interesting: it shows how to decode UTF-8 bytes manually. Of course, it's much more sensible to use the built-in methods, the purpose of my code is to show how the encoding works.

Comment: When I execute 'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")` I get an error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Check @hiro protagonist answer for that. You need to do it on byte string

Comment: I believe this only works for python2 and not 3

Answer (score 0):

in python 3 you'd need to [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) the `bytes` that are your encoded string:

```
b'Schutzt\xc3\xbcren'.decode("utf-8")
```

in python 2 the `b` is not necessary (here the distinction between bytes and strings is less strict...).